# Having problem defining the condition as it is based on a different loop than the task

Tags: ansible

I am trying to make a playbook that will check if something exists and depending on the results, it will execute a command.

I have simplified the problem but here is the gist of it :

I have a list, called "list" :

sample1
sample2
sample3
sample4

I will start by checking if a directory with this name exists.

```yaml
- name: Status
  shell: ls -l | grep {{ item }} | grep -v grep | wc -l
  loop:  "{{ list }}"
  register: status
```

then i ll determine whether the folder exists or not (not sure if i need this step...)

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: {{ item.item }} exists 
  loop:  "{{ status.results }}"
  when: item.stdout != "0"
  register: check

- debug:
    msg: {{ item.item }} does not exist 
  loop:  "{{ status.results }}"
  when: item.stdout = "0"
  register: check
```

the next step is where i am stuck... cant really find the right syntax or way to do this.. Anyway, i want to check if my folder exists or not, if it does not i want to create it.

```yaml
- name: creation
  shell: mkdir {{ item }}
  loop: "{{ list }}"
  when: check.results.item.stdout != "0"
```

as it need to check for every results from the list, my condition is based on the "check.results" and not the "list" defined in the loop.
I dont really know if this can be written as such

Comment: Where is the actual issue here? Please shorten you question with minimal reproducable code, and show us what you've already done to fix it.

Comment: I have modified the original question to be more explicit. Basically i cant figure out how to the make the condition work in my task "Stopping"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common misunderstanding. Ansible is about describing the expected state of the remote system and is generally idempotent for most of its modules. Running the same task an infinite number of times will lead to the same result on the target. In other words, don't check if a directory exists to later give the order to create it. Just describe the expected state: **the directory must exist**.

This can be done in a single task with the [`ansible.builtin.file` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html)

```yaml
- name: Make sure needed directories exist
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
  loop: "{{ list }}"
```

As the description name in my example suggests, this will create the needed dirs for those who do not exist reporting `CHANGE` and leave the others alone reporting `OK`.

Tip: whenever you are going to use `shell` hold a minute and check the documentation for a module doing the job. In most cases there is one. For example you can use the [`ansible.builtin.find` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html) rather than looking for files with the shell.

---

In case you still want to apply a bad solution, the answer was already in my previous version of the answer and is also (again) in you debug task. You just have to apply the same receipe.

```yaml
- name: creation
  shell: mkdir {{ item.item }}
  loop: "{{ status.results }}"
  when: item.stdout != "0"
```

Note that this would work with a correct module as well but does not really make sense

```yaml
- name: Make sure missing directories are created
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "{{ item.item }}"
    state: directory
  loop: "{{ status.results }}"
  when: item.stdout != "0"
```

Both of these examples require of course to run your previous task (which should be refactored to a `find` module as stated earlier)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, never used filters and it looks like it will be useful to improve my code. Nevertheless, the task "Stopping" loops on "jvmStatusList", its only the condition that should use "statusResult" and i cant figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section. Then [edit] your question to add more info. No one at this point has any idea what your input variables look like.

Comment: fair enough, i have simplified everything and provided a reproducible example like requested.

Comment: This is actually a totally different question which will have a very different response. Updating.

Comment: the directory was just to provide an example, guess i chose the wrong one :x
how would you proceed if there was no builtin ansible module?

Comment: When there is really no module, you use `command`. If you cannot use `command` (because of pipes or redirections), you use `shell`. In most situation, there is a module. ansible has plethora of modules between core, community, third parties (over a thousand). And last, you can write your own module.